# Building in VS 2019 in linux fail and give "error \Linux.targets(514,5): error : One or more errors occurred" but not explaining any thing

Tags: c++, linux, build, visual-studio-2019, target

I am using visual studio 2019 (C++) for projects on Linux machine.
The build fails and give me this error:

```
1>Copying sources remotely to '192.168.3.144'
1>Validating architecture
1>Validating architecture
1>Starting remote build
1>Compiling sources:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(514,5): error : One or more errors occurred.
1>Done building project "OM.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

But doesn't show what the error is.
In the above tag (Linux.targets(514,5)) there are many assignment actions which I do not know their meaning.
Can someone guide or explain what can be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming it's using something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=msvc-160 the project properties should have a log file configured or you can configure one. Then more information should be in that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It is useful.
I  forgot about it :-).
Found some issues there - hope those are the reasons.